# CSS style issue in table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have use the className like below code snippet.

Code Snippet

```
<tr class="gridrowtaskIdlevel0 e-alt_row e-gridtreerowexpand">
    <td class="e-rowcell ">
        <div style="height: 20px;">
            <div class="intend" style="width: 0px; height: 1px; float: left; display: inline-block;">
            </div>

            <div class="e-gridtreeexpand" style="float: left; display: inline-block;">
            </div>

            <div class="e-cell" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                6
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td class="e-rowcell">Implementation Phase 2</td>
    <td class="e-rowcell">02/15/2010</td>
    <td class="e-rowcell"></td>
    <td class="e-rowcell">8</td>
    <td class="e-rowcell">50</td>
    <td class="e-rowcell"></td>
    <td class="e-extendcolumn"></td>
</tr>
```

Note: here class Name = gridrowtaskIdlevel0 e-alt_row e-gridtreerowexpand

i have tried to apply css style(display) for this row based on some condition like following
two ways

1. $('.gridrowtaskIdlevel0').addClass('e-hide');

CSS:

```
.e-hide{
display:none;
}
```

2. $('.gridrowtaskIdlevel0').css({'display':'none'});

how to apply css style to tr in runtime

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand what runtime do you mean, but if you just need make this code working - you need put it in some event: click on smth, doc.ready and etc.

Please, try such construction:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gridrowtaskIdlevel0').addClass('e-hide');      // the 1st way
    // or
    $('.gridrowtaskIdlevel0').css({'display':'none'}); // the 2nd way
    // or
    $('.gridrowtaskIdlevel0').hide();                  // the 3rd way
});
```

But If you will use the 1st way you also need to add css (same to your).

I recommend use 1st or 3rd variant, but all of they will work similarly.

Good luck!

Comment: Just a heads up, I think you meant you need to add CSS if you use the *1st way*.

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>`s don't always do well with all styles.

Here's an example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/LAhmg/) that shows how you might focus on `<td>`s.

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody, th, td {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
}

tr.foo {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2){
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
```